# special characters in windows command line

Tags: curl, encoding, cmd, special-characters

I have a curl command which I try to execute in the command line. When I paste the command to cmd, I get these question marks.

```
C:\\development\\curl\\curl.exe -H "charset=utf-8" -u admin:test -X POST --data-urlencode "LabelA=الطباعة" http://192.168.1.10:7502/content/language-master/ar/jcr:content
```

[image]

What do I have to do? Any help.

Thanks in advance,
yab86

Comment: Try running the command. It should work if curl.exe is a Unicode application (not legacy ANSI). The boxed question mark glyphs have nothing at all to do with cmd.exe. The current font of the console (conhost.exe) doesn't support the script, and may not support it in general. The console is a classic Windows NT application that doesn't support non-BMP characters, complex scripts, automatic font fallback, etc, as opposed to a modern app that uses DirectWrite. However, its input buffer should have the exact UTF-16 text pasted from the clipboard, which is what CMD reads via `ReadConsoleW`.

Comment: @eryksun It's not the font that restricts this, but the CMD environment itself. Display in CMD is limited to code page 437, the legacy PC-compatible extended ASCII character set.

Comment: @Tzalumen, cmd.exe doesn't render text to the screen. That's the job of the console, which is hosted by conhost.exe. To read a command line, CMD calls `ReadConsoleW` which does a cooked (processed) read, in which case the console implements a command-line editor that supports the arrow keys, backspace, F7 history, etc, and reads until the user presses enter. The console renders text to its screen using legacy code that's limited to the basic multilingual plane, simple scripts, and a single font (no automatic fallback), but it still returns exactly what the user entered as UTF-16 encoded text.

Comment: @Tzalumen, the console's input codepage defaults to OEM, which is 437 in the U.S. The legacy codepage is used when an application calls `ReadConsoleA` or `ReadFile`. But CMD is a Unicode application that uses the wide-character (UTF-16) functions `ReadConsoleW`, `WriteConsoleW`, etc. CMD does use the console input or output codepages in a few cases, notably when reading from a pipe in a `for /f` loop, when decoding a batch script, and (by default unless `/U` is used) when redirecting output of its internal commands (e.g. `dir`) to a pipe or disk file. You can change the codepage via chcp.com.